# Combining Raster and Polygons using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am struggling with GIS (Esri).

I have the following overlaying data:

1) Several Polygons of suitable areas (m²) for the deployment of Photovoltaic
2) A TIF-raster (asc also available) of possible Photovoltaic Power Output (kWh/kWp) in different areas which is based on average sunshine duration per year.

I would now like to combine both 1) and 2) in order to see which Polygons/areas exhibit the highest possible Photovoltaic Power Output.

How can I combine both layers?

I'm clueless. For example, the Power Output for the upper polygon would be much higher than for the lower ones (see picture).

[image: Sun data and polygons]

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to do is compute "zonal statistics" of the raster within your polygons (the zone definition layer). So, something like the maximum or mean value of pixels contained in each polygon might be what you are after, depending on what is most meaningful to you.

See: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics.htm

Comment: Hi Jeremy. Thanks for your answer. Do I need to have any programming skills for that? Looks pretty complicated. I'll dig deeper into it the next days and will ask here again if I have any questions.

Basically, I'd be already happy if I could allocate each of my polygons the respective PV Power Output. Mean value of pixels contained in each polygon sounds good. Isn't there any easier way? Like intersecting the polygons with the raster by transforming the raster into a polygon or sth like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Basically, I'd be already happy if I could allocate each of my polygons one PV Power Output.

Comment: Hi again. The zonal statistics tool works great! Thanks a lot for your answer. Best